# Using two for loops and if statement for populating a new column in an existing dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to "fill" a column of a dataset by combining information by two other columns. More specifically, I am trying the following:

```
a <- data.frame(gender_p1 = c("man", "woman","man","man"), gender_p2 = c("man", "man","woman","woman"), couple = c(""))
> a
  gender_p1 gender_p2 couple
1       man       man       
2     woman       man       
3       man     woman       
4       man     woman
```

I want to iterate through a[1] and a[2] to populate respectively a[3] column.
I tried to use a double for loop and an ifelse statement within, without any success. Is there any better approach for it?
Thanks in advance for any possible proposal.

Comment: How do you want to combine `a[1]` and `a[2]` columns to get `a[3]` column? What is the logic there? What should `couple` column hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data has not super many rows, check out `dplyr` (or the `tidyverse` in general). You can use `mutate` to create new columns based on some conditions:

```
a <- data.frame(gender_p1 = c("man", "woman","man","man"), gender_p2 = c("man", "man","woman","woman"))

library(dplyr)

a <- a %>% 
  mutate(same_sex = if_else(
    gender_p1 == gender_p2,
    TRUE,
    FALSE
  ))

a
  gender_p1 gender_p2 same_sex
1       man       man     TRUE
2     woman       man    FALSE
3       man     woman    FALSE
4       man     woman    FALSE
```

Comment: @akrun fair point; I've included it to give the OP a basic structure to use it for more complex assignments